# Jquery functions are not working because of Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null

Tags: jquery, html

i am using a bootstrap template that contains,

jquery-1.9.1.min.js

jquery.flot.js

jquery.flot.resize.js

jquery.dataTables.js .

```
 <?php 

       ob_start();
       $path = '../';
       $title = 'Leave Dates';
       include($path.'header.php');
       include($path.'side.php');
       include("brnch_session.php");

       $sql_br =  mysql_query("SELECT br_name FROM branch_data WHERE ID = '$br_id'");
       $res_br = mysql_fetch_row($sql_br);

    ?>



      <!-- live search -->
      <link href="<?php echo $path ?>/css/live_search.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">


     <!--date picker files-->
     <link href="../datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ua.js" charset="UTF-8"></script> 

         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#txt_check").keyup(function(){
                    $("#txt_check").css("background-color", "RED");
                    alert('you cant');
                });
            });
          </script>
```

html

```
  <?php include('mini_top.php'); ?>   

   <?php
    $run=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_infor where br_code='$br_id'");
    $nor= mysql_num_rows($run);
    ?>

        <h3 style="margin-left:2%;">  Leave Dates </h3>
        <div align="left" style="margin-left:2%;width:100%;height:400px">
        <table class="leav_date">
            <tr>
                <td> DATE 
                    <input type="text" id="txt_check" name="txt_check" />
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCFFFF" align="center">                  
                 <div class="controls">
                    <div  align="left" class="col-sm-10 input-append date leav_date"        
                    data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" 
                    data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                    <input size="16" type="text" name="leav_date" 
                    value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" required readonly 
                    class="form-control" 
                    style="width:180px;height:35px">
                    <span class="add-on" style="height:25px"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <form method="post">
        <table width=""  border="1" style="margin:2%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" class="head_tb">
          <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>  
               <?php
               if(isset($_POST['year'])){
                   $year_sel = $_POST['year'];
               }else{
                   $year_sel = date('Y');
               }

               if(isset($_POST['month'])){
                   $cret_d = date('Y').'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.date('d');
                   $date = date_create($cret_d);
                   $mon_sel = date_format($date,"M");
               }else{
                   $mon_sel = date('M');
               }
               ?>           
               <input type="number" value="<?php echo $year_sel; ?>"  name="year" style="height:30px;width:70px"/>              
            </td> 
            <td  valign="center">
                Class
            </td>  
            <td>
            <select name="bt_id" class="span8"  style="width:150px;">
               <?php
                    $btch = mysql_query("SELECT Batch_no, cls_room_id FROM cls_room_tb
                                        WHERE cls_brnch_id = '$br_id'");
                    while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($btch)){
                        if($_POST['bt_id'] == $rec[1]){ 
                            echo "<option value='".$rec[1]."' selected>".$rec[0]."</option>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<option value='".$rec[1]."'>".$rec[0]."</option>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>

            </select>               
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="load" class="btn btn-success" value="Load" />
            </td>
          </tr>          
        </table>
        </form>
       </div>
    </div> 




         </div>

        <!--/.content-->
      </div>

      <!--/.span9-->
      </div>

      </div>
      <!--/.container-->

      </div>
       <!--/.wrapper-->

       <?php include($path.'footer.php'); ?>       
           <script type="text/javascript">    
             $('.leav_date').datetimepicker({
               language:  'fr',
                weekStart: 1,
                todayBtn:  1,
                autoclose: 1,
                todayHighlight: 1,
                startView: 2,
                minView: 2,
                forceParse: 0
                   });  
          </script>
```

when i try to run the code it gives a error like

Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null jquery.flot.js:711

Comment: where the style need to be updated, for the body tag!

Comment: Are you referencing the scripts in correct order?

Comment: yes if i remove the jquery.flot.js , jquery.flot.resize.js , jquery.dataTables.js file then the jquery is working

Comment: Are you calling $.plot(...) anywhere in your code?

Comment: no i don't calling in any where

Comment: This error comes when Plot method is called without assigning width and height to the Placeholder. It is not possible to find the issue with limited information. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: now i have put the full page

Comment: Can you post the HTML, the HTML source of web page generated by this code? I don't see any call to Plot in here. But may be one of your included pages do that. I can't even find links to flot scripts.

Comment: can you tell me how to find the Plot callng area, I am new to jquery...  in my include pages i didn't call the $.plot(...) anywhere

Comment: can you tell me how to find the Plot callng area, I am new to jquery...  in my include pages i didn't call the $.plot(...) anywhere.. but i have put  jquery.flot.js files to end of the page.. like  Ali Sheikhpour said.. now jquery functions working but still the error appera in console

Comment: It is hard to tell without looking at the code. You can search for plot() in your project. Anyway I didn't find flot files anywhere in you posted code.

Answer (score 1):

When using *jquery.flot.js* make sure that all **scripts comes after their related html elements**. Also set width and height for elements that *flot* is applied on them.